# SQL: Subtracting certain rows with restrictions from a data table into a new table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I Have a data table in postgresql which has these columns and some rows like this:

| st | epochnum | satnum | l1 | l2 | c1 | p1 | p2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 |
| 20 | 1 | 1 | 30 | 41 | 52 | 63 | 74 |
| 20 | 1 | 2 | 75 | 76 | 87 | 88 | null |
| 20 | 2 | 1 |  | ... |  |  |  |

I want to get some pairs of rows that have the same value for epochnum and satnum but have different value in "st". By the way, I have a list that specifies which "st" pairs should be subtracted. Its just another table that looks like this:

| st1 | st2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |

The rows in the first table have to be subtracted in l1,l2,c1,p1 and p2 with same epochnum and satnum according to this table and then inserted into a new table like this:

| epochnum | st1 | st2 | satnum | dl1 | dl2 | dc1 | dp1 | dp2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | 1 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | 60 |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | 2 | 65 | 65 | 75 | 75 | null |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The actual data has more than 400000 rows that has same epochnums and satnums like this. I have tried java programming in net-beans and used loops to simply get queries for each row and make the new table.

But I think maybe it is not efficient and unnecessarily takes long time due to the lots of queries that has to be done in java.

I wonder if there is a way that this can be done using just a few queries, or creating extra tables and .... I haven't come up with the best solution yet.

Comment: I'm confused.  If the data is in Postgres, why is the question tagged SQL Server?

Comment: I'm just asking for the right SQL queries to do the job. I guess you are right. I'll remove the sql-server tag. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `join`s like this?

```
select t1.st, t1.epochnum, t1.satnum,
       (t2.l1 - t1.l1),
       (t2.l2 - t1.l2),
       (t2.p1 - t1.p1),
       (t2.p2 - t1.p2)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.epochnum = t2.epochnum and
        t1.satnum = t2.satnum join
     pairs p
     on t1.st = p.st1 and t2.st = p.st2
```

Comment: yes! that was it man! :) thank you so much. You know I'm kinda new to the sql queries and database stuff and ... and I'm just fascinated about how it works and understands the exact thing that we want :)). dozens of programming codes (not in sql) can't do the job like this. This is good :)